# I have problem to execute command in Linux

Tags: php, ubuntu, yii2

I have problem to execute command in Linux with php 
I want to generate sitemap with this command

```
php /var/www/xxx.com/html/app/yii sitemap/someAction
```

when I paste this command in the ssh Its work prefectly
but when I use this command like this :

```
$command="php /var/www/xxx.com/html/app/yii sitemap/someAction"
exec($command, $output, $return);
```

the return is 0 and its show there isn't any error but the sitemap isn't generate 
I check php functions and exec isn't in that list 
I use PHP 7.2 and ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I'm guessing the space might be throwing it off, so try `yii\ sitemap`?

Comment: Its the same command in ssh and thats work prefect, this type of command  for run yii console command

Comment: It is the permission issue. Your web server don't have permission to run system comand.

Comment: thank you for your answer , i have question , is that not throw exception? or return another number for return exec ?